# Declaring type "number" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Greeting,

i was trying to declare a number variable as(any number with prefix zero) :

```
let num1: number = 01;
```

but this is throwing an error and intellisense is to use "0o1" which would be an octal number. So is there a way to declare a number with prefix zero in TypeScript.[image]

PS : New to TypeScript

Comment: What do you mean, a number with prefix zero? `1 === 01 === 001 === ...`

Comment: Numbers are there to do math, and prefix zeros do not exist there.

Comment: What is the purpose of this prefix? Probably you want you use number as string?

Comment: what if i am creating an an interface which have id as member and i want it to be as 01, 02 , 03... ? and it has to be type number

Comment: Then don't use a number, use a string.

Comment: Why do the zeros matter? Is `01` really different than `1` ?

Comment: no but just to display it directly on html without prefixing zero later. as we can declare it in Javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Octal literals are not available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467148/octal-literals-are-not-available-when-targeting-ecmascript-5-and-higher)

Comment: This is because use of octal literals was supported in ES3 and denoted by a starting 0. Since ES5 these have been deprecated as these are ambiguous and can lead to errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If variable is a type of number. It cannot have a prefix 0. If you want to add it you need to make string out of it and pad with 0.

For example:

```
if (number.toString().length < 2) {
   return '0' + number;
}
```

Comment: why not `if (number > -10 && number < 10)`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a good first answer. Keep going :)

Comment: is there a way as it is in JavaScript?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript so the basics are applicable here also